# Freeing workflow from CVS concepts/limitations

Tags: git, version-control, cvs

I’m migrating our VCS from CVS to Git and I’m still struggling trying to best adapt our workflow to fit Git, but I still have some doubts. We don’t have a production environment, we periodically release versions and is up to our customers to deploy them on a production environment. So our workflow is a bit different from the teams out there.
We often have several versions being developed in parallel, that at some point need to be integrated with higher versions. Here's a simple example:
[image]

Now, imagine that `V1.0` is finished and is being released to our customers. At this point, we need to merge this branch with `V2.0` and `V3.0`, that continue under development (to keep it simple, I’m not considering the cases where changes may not apply to some of the branches, e.g. a fix on a functionality that was discontinued on a later branch), which will create an history similar to this one:

[image]
With `V1.0` “closed”, we start working on `V1.1`. The way we worked with CVS, we would have a branch representing the `HEAD` for each version, e.g. `V01_HEAD`, created a new branch from there, e.g. `V01_00`, do some work, commit, switch to `V01_HEAD`, merge from `V01_00`, commit, tag, switch to `V02_HEAD` and merge `V01_HEAD`, commit, switch to `V03_HEAD` and merge `V02_HEAD`, commit, and so on. Afterwards, we would create `V01_01` from `V01_HEAD` and the cicle repeats. As you can imagine, keeping everything up to date is tricky, laborious, painful and merge conflicts are extremely frequent, because we need to keep track of all the branches under development and need to be sure we don’t forget to merge to one of the upper branches. It is also very common having the same blocks of code being changed in different branches, hence the conflicts.
The challenges increase when we sometimes have 4 or more parallel developments. The master’s branch sole purpose is to serve as a base for new versions.
We also have additional challenges. Imagine that someone is working on `V1.12` and does substancial changes on several classes. Other collaborators are working on `V2.5` and others on `V3.0`. Until `V1.12` is merged, the other versions will be basing their work on possibly deprecated code.

Does this same philosophy make any sense on Git or is it better to have less and longer running branches (e.g. `V1`, `V2`, `V3`, etc.) and just tag the commit before merging it to higher branches?

Since this is a fresh start and Git offers so much more options when compared to CVS, I just want to be sure that the workflow we choose is not going to introduce unnecessary entropy. I need solid advices from Git/version control experts.

I hope I was clear enough explaining the problem.

Comment: I suggest checking out [my own question about branches and tags](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/165725/git-branching-and-tagging-best-practices) on [SoftwareEngineering.SE] (formerly Programmers) when I was first learning Git.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll have a look.

Comment: This is not an answer _per se_ but if you're using CVS, chances are this is an old project and people are set in their CVS ways. Give your team way more time than you expect to just learn to understand git. (If your team is small enough that this is possible, force them to do some sort of training, or hold regular tutorial sessions. Only then will they be able to understand all the "crazy stuff" you might be asking them to do in git.) At first with git, maybe just do your same CVS workflow until they're ready for the second big change.

Comment: @Mort, That is exactly what I'm doing. I've dedicated the last weeks to read all sort of tutorials and wrote a 150 page document focused on using Git in our environment to give to all team members. I'll also preparing a training session (one morning or so). That's way I want to have a clean start, I want people to forget about CVS, otherwise they will never fully understand how Git operates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the philosophy also make sense on Git. But you can also design a different structure, as you need to develop v1.x, v2.x and v3.x concurrently, you can create 3 release branches v1, v2 and v3. The version v1.0, v1.1, v1.2 etc can be marked by tag and commit message, so you can easily find them. There is [a successful git branch module](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) for your reference (as your requirement is differently from it, if you want to apply this module you must make some changes).

```
C1---C2------C3------------------C7
       \       \                  \
        \       C6--C8--C10(V2)    C9--C11(V3)
         \              / ______________/
          C4-----------C5---C12---C13 (v1)
                       |     |     |
                     V1.0   v1.1   v1.2
```

And it’s not necessary to tag the commit before merging, you can add tag for history commit by `git tag –a v1.0 <commit id> -m 'message'`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, the link seems very helpful.

Comment: With my pleasure. If the answer helps you, please mark it. It will help others who have similar questions :)

Comment: I will, I'm just waiting for further contributions (if any) before accepting an answer.